# PWA only runs in Chrome on Desktop?

Tags: web, https, progressive-web-apps

Created a simple PWA, made the manifest file and service worker and it works great in Chrome on my iMac.  Looking at the console, I can see that the service worker is registered and running and it recognizes the manifest file. Simulate network loss and it still runs just fine like it's supposed to. All good, right?

When I serve it from an HTTPS it opens in the browser on the phone just fine and adds to the home screen just as it should but when I try to run it from the icon on the home screen, all I get is a blank white screen.

If I delete the icon and then serve it from an HTTP connection and save it to the home screen, it does everything just as it should, runs from the icon you place on the home screen (when done from http) but of course won't run offline.

What am I doing wrong?  Not even sure where to start looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem could be the CROS access origin for HTTPS requests between your PWA and your API server . had the same issue with my PWA. it worked fine in chrome or desktop and run fine the first time I was opening it in mobile chrome but when the services worker get registered it return CROS access origin.
to debug this problem I recommend using chrome inspect on your mobile device.
you can find the guide [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/)

check

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin

between API and PWA servers.
you must allow your PWA URL to access to API server . you can either use the PWA URL or * to access all URLs.

check

> Access-Control-Allow-Headers

in your API server.
if you are sending authentication or cache-control header with your requests you must add them to Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

and your PWA and API URL must have a valid SSL certificate.

also, check start_url in manifest.json

you have to set the full URL including protocol in start_url, index.html is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I'll look into them.  The PWA and API both have SSL certs.  I'll check what's going on in Chrome on the mobile device.

Comment: @TomH also check start_url in manifest.json

Comment: Ok...what am I looking for?  the app is being served from a folder in the root as in: https://www.URL.com/app/index.html.  The Manifest just has index.html for star-url.

Comment: you have to set the full URL including protocol in start_url, index.html is not necessary . https://url.com/app @TomH

Comment: pfndesign:  That was it!  I changed/cleaned up the path in start_url and it works now like it should!   Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: @TomH happy to help . i updated the answer